# Proxmox setup with four different disks

Tags: storage, proxmox

I have a lab server Im looking to turn into a Proxmox server. I have four different storage disks:

- 2.5TB
- 1TB
- 500GB
- 256GB

I have proxmox installed on the fifth. Question is what do I do with these different size disks? Im just running some linux or windows VMs and network security tools like firewalls and such. Not doing DBs or NAS type applications. What setup would you use (ZFS pool, different discrete storages, etc)?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a question and answer site for professional and enthusiast programmers for questions regarding programming. You might want to ask your question at [Unix&Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/), [Superuser](https://superuser.com/) or [Serverfault](https://serverfault.com) instead.